# While loop with class objects, reset afterwards

Tags: javascript

Due to Js referencing objects, I am in a bit of a pickle.

I have a Js "class" that creates a new player. The class has a few different variables, strings and array etc and some functions for checking certain things to do with those variables.

I am doing a while loop (ends when one player is declared dead) and after the loop is done, I want to "reset" the instantiated classes so I can run the loop again (a nested while loop).

e.g.

```
function Player(name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = 100;

    this.isnotdead = function()
    {
        return hp > 0;
    }
}

var player1 = new Player('player1');
var player2 = new Player('player2');

while(war_is_happening)
{
  while(player1.isnotdead || player2.isnotdead)
  {
    fight(player1, player2); // one of the players is killed
  }

  declareWinner(); // one player is a winner, lets fight again

  resertPlayers() // I want to start the nearest while loop again, but with fresh variables for player 1 and player2
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Previously I've used stuff like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(player1))` to make a copy of the object, but now my object (class) has methods inside it so this doesn't work.

Comment: Show the class definition of Player.

Comment: You might like to look at the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Comment: `while(player1.isnotdead || player2.isnotdead)` - probably `&&`

Comment: @Igor is needs to be OR, as the fight is over when one of them is dead, not both :)

Comment: @MrPablo - but certainly they only can fight when both of them are not dead

Comment: Easier to confirm that Igor is correct when you read it as **(player1.isAlive && player2.isAlive)** which is the same thing.

Comment: `while(player1.isnotdead() || player2.isnotdead())` and inside `isnotdead`  should check `this.hp > 0`

Comment: Here's what you want to say in English: "While they are both alive." This is the same as "While they are both not dead," which is the same as "While P1 is not dead AND P2 is not dead." So you want &&. Your current code will keep going until they are both dead. (It will keep going if P1 is alive OR if P2 is alive. This will only be false when they are both dead.)

Comment: Add to that I think your method should do away with the negative. `isdead` is a lot easier to wrap your head round when using in boolean logic - it removes the possible double negative of `!isnotdead()` <-- is that alive or dead. warps my brain thinking about it

Comment: Ok guys, please ignore my crappy example :) My point is about "resetting" the class. I have a very "hackish" way right now, which adds a function that simply replaces the player hp with a new integer of 100., but I hate duplication :(

Answer (score 2):

```
function resertPlayers() {
  player1 = new Player('player1');
  player2 = new Player('player2');
}
```

Comment: What if player actually maintains their score in the game? You just overwrote that property.

Comment: @Jamiec - I cannot read the OP's mind :), but I can read the text of the question - "but with fresh variables for player 1 and player2"

Comment: True, Im just stating the obvious though. `"reset" the instantiated classes` not `recreate` is what they asked for. This is truely the most obvious answer though!

Comment: He did comment that after fight(..) one of them would be killed, i.e. have 0 hp, so there is little point in maintaining the hp and I don't see another score field.

Answer (score 0):

So as I commented, the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) is a good place to start, you essentially take a snapshot of your object when it is constructed, and restore that whenever you like.

You could code this like:

```
function Player(name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.hp = 100;

    var initialState = {hp:100};

    this.isnotdead = function()
    {
        return hp > 0;
    }

    this.restore = function(){
       this.hp = initialState.hp;
    }
}
```

and call `player1.restore()` when you want to reset. This assumes there are *other* properties you do NOT want to reset between games. If you have none then @Igor's answer is the obvious (and, best) solution.

Comment: Yea, I gotta figured this out. I'm not a fan, as it's duplicated code, but so be it!

Comment: @MrPablo there is no need to duplicate any code, I showed an example of hard-coding the `hp` but if you had lots of properties you wanted to reset that can be done without duplicating anything